# OpenCL memory allocation limit on GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu

When a memory allocation happens in OpenCL using `clCreateBuffer` and writing happen with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, how to decide which memory to allocate (CPU memory or GPU memory)
If the GPU memory is being allocated, will the program fail if the allocation is greater than the memory limit? (or will there be something like paging)

Answer (score 1):

`clCreateBuffer()` will return a null buffer and set the error code to `CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE` if the requested buffer size is greater than the device's `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` (which can be queried with the `clGetDeviceInfo()` function).

See the [documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) for `clCreateBuffer()` for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me what memory will it try to allocate? (GPU or CPU) Is there any default?

Comment: `clCreateBuffer()` allocates memory on the device. It can also optionally allocate memory on the host if you pass the `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` flag.